# How to search and replace in *open buffers*

Tags: buffers, search, icicles

I want to interactively search and replace in all (or, preferably, a regexp subset of) my *buffers* (**not files**).

### Scenario

- Being a pack-rat sort of guy, I never delete my buffers until I'm sure I don't need them anymore (e.g. new project), or until the system crashes and I lose them. So I know that all the files I've modified (the targets of the search and replace) are in a buffer somewhere.
- The files are strewn all over creation so I can't use `Dired`.
- There are 10k files in scope, so I'd prefer to avoid file-based operations (*though I've already wasted so much time on this I've eclipsed the amount of time I would have saved not using the file-based approach*).

### What I'm doing now

Right now I'm using `multi-occur-in-matching-buffers` and repeating a query replace for each matching file.

*I'm told Icicles will do this, but reading the manual, I can't make heads or tails of how to do it. (I used `M-99 M-x icicle-search`; I get prompted for a "context", which I can't find a definition for in the manual and furnishes as a completion a list of previous mini-buffer entries, which doesn't make sense to me.) Icicles is far more than I need, but if I have to use it, I will.*

### Things I've tried

- I tried `tags-query-replace` but it doesn't work; I always get zero matches, even though it ends bringing up a buffer with a match in plain sight.
- I've read the FAQ (see responses above).

I may end up having to use file-based operations (which are annoying because I have to find and reload each file manually)

Since Icicles supposedly does what I want I thought I'd throw the question out. The other option is to use the Refactor facility in our IDE but that wouldn't be Emacs!! ❤

Comment: mark your buffers in ibuffer, then use Q or I, after doing the replacement, save unsaved buffers in ibuffer

Comment: @Muihlinn Good enough, thank you! Feel free to post as an answer; otherwise I will. I hadn't even heard of ibuffer.

Answer (score 5):

`Ibuffer` is what you're looking for.

- `M-x ibuffer`
- Mark your buffers any way you prefer: using `m` to mark them manually, `% g` by regexp content-matching, `* M` to mark by major mode, or whatever other option which suits your fancy -err needs.
- Use `Q` to make a regexp search and replace on marked buffers or `I` for plain search and replace.
- Do the replaces, then go back to ibuffer
- `S` will save the marked buffers.

There are more ways to achieve the same using other popular tools, but `ibuffer` is powerful, fit your needs, comes with emacs and can do a lot more than this pretty much effortlessly.

To learn more about it, press `?` on a `ibuffer` buffer.